# Newtonsoft.json version error

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, .net-assembly

I am using TFS server and just get all the latest version from the server and when I run the code it show `newtonsoft.json` doesn't match with the dependency. So I remove it and just install it again (latest version 9.0.1). But when I right click on the `newtonsoft.json` property it shows version 4.5.0 (shown in the below image)
[image]

And when I run this program I got this error

> "An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

[image]

I tried the all steps from the following link

[How can I fix assembly version conflicts with JSON.NET after updating NuGet package references in a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498074/how-can-i-fix-assembly-version-conflicts-with-json-net-after-updating-nuget-pack)

Answer (score 0):

try to update the library.Right the below command in package manager console.

```
Update-Package –reinstall Newtonsoft.Json
```

Comment: or use this commnad
**Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json**