# Weird .NET Assembly warnings when building my .NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, assemblybinding

When I build my ASP.NET web application I'm seeing the following weird warnings in my build output.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Hornet.Api, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" and "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed". Choosing "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" and "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed". Choosing "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" arbitrarily.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" from Version "9.0.0.0" [] to Version "10.0.0.0" [C:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Api\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "2.2.0.0" [] to Version "2.3.0.0" [C:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Api\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.2.3.0\lib\net46\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Text.RegularExpressions, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.10.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7\Facades\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll] to Version "4.1.0.0" [C:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Api\packages\System.Text.RegularExpressions.4.3.0\lib\net463\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Net.Http, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7\System.Net.Http.dll] to Version "4.1.1.0" [C:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Api\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.1\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.20.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll] to Version "4.1.1.0" [C:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Api\packages\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Reflection, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.10.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7\Facades\System.Reflection.dll] to Version "4.1.1.0" [C:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Api\packages\System.Reflection.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Reflection.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.20.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7\Facades\System.Runtime.dll] to Version "4.1.1.0" [C:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Api\packages\System.Runtime.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.IO.Compression, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7\System.IO.Compression.dll] to Version "4.1.2.0" [C:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Api\packages\System.IO.Compression.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.IO.Compression.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime.Extensions, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.10.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll] to Version "4.1.1.0" [C:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Api\packages\System.Runtime.Extensions.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Api\packages\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core.2.0.4\lib\net45\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime.InteropServices, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.20.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll] to Version "4.1.1.0" [C:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Api\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.4.3.0\lib\net463\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Linq, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7\Facades\System.Linq.dll] to Version "4.1.1.0" [C:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Api\packages\System.Linq.4.3.0\lib\net463\System.Linq.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.3.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.RegularExpressions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Extensions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>
```

My solution has two projects:

- Website (ASP.NET v4.7)
- Tests (.NET v4.7)

So i'm not sure where these warnings are applying to - which project?

Also, I've checked both the (website proj) `web.config` and (tests proj) `app.config` for the `AssemblyBindings` and they are all pointing to the latest .. like this is in both files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

 .....
```

So why is the compiler thinking there's a conflict with various versions of Newtonsoft.Json ? I've only installed one version ...

I've also got assemblybindings in place and they all seem to point to the latest version installed, also.

#### Update

- This is a snippet of my `packages.config`

`<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net47" />`

That's in BOTH projects, btw

and this...
[image]

#### Update 2

here's the `hintpath` which is the same for both projects...

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

#### Update 3

OK - this is interesting.

- Turn on `VERBOSE` build info
- I can now see *heaps* more data. The first warning is saying that my [nuget package `Google.Apis.QpxExpress.v1`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.QPXExpress.v1/) ends up having a dependency on `Google.Apis.Core` which has a dependency on Json v 9.0.0.
- My web.config file HAS the binding redirects! (see above).

Comment: So you are sure you have json.net version 10.0.0.0 referenced?

Comment: Updated Opening Post.

Comment: Can you check the .csproj files to ensure the `<HintPath>` for those assemblies isn't pointing to a different version?

Comment: Updated OP again. :)

Comment: did any of you find an answer , I have done all those steps. and nothing

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/21499438/1726296