# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage and System.Net.Http conflict

Tags: c#, .net, azure-storage

I have just updated all packages in my application (which consists of many projects). One of these packages was **System.Net.Http**. Now I am getting an error:

> 'Storage' with identity 'Storage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Net.Http' with identity 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I was hoping I could add a redirect, so in my **Storage** project, I put this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

in the **app.config**, but I still get the error.
I guess my question is: Can I use a binding redirect for a referenced library or do I have to rollback my **Update-Package** and put version constraints on **System.Net.Http**??

Comment: Why not redirect to 4.2, i.e. `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />`?

Comment: I tried that, didn't work.

Comment: You need to reference the v4.2 library of System.Net.Http, and set the newVersion to 4.2 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after hours of playing, looking around on the internet and solutions posted here, I finally got this to work.
Here are the steps I did.

1. Rename **System.Net.Http.dll** to **System.Net.Http.dl_** in this folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib
2. For each project that references **System.Net.Http**, make sure they are using the NuGet package and not the one from extensions
3. Build your project and look through each of the **Refreences** for each project, check the version of the **System.Net.Http** dll (right click > properties)
4. Unload the project and search for **System.Net.Http** and make sure they are the same version as in step 3 (You can try setting them all to version 4.2.0.0, but I had issues with this)

Once this is done, trying rebuilding your project, it should build and should run.
I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

[Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498074/how-can-i-fix-assembly-version-conflicts-with-json-net-after-updating-nuget-pack) for soloving Assembly uses version X which has a higher version than referenced assemblu error:

Open packages.config and delete the System.Net.Http entry.
Save and build then readd assemble from nuget.
Build and run.

When you compile apps in Visual Studio that target the .NET Framework 4.5.1 and later versions, **binding redirects may be automatically added** to the app configuration file to override assembly unification.

In Visual Studio, select the project in `Solution Explorer`, and then choose `Open Folder in File Explorer` from the shortcut menu. In File Explorer, find the project (.csproj or .vbproj) file and open it in Notepad.

Add the following element to the first configuration property group (under the  tag):

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection).

Comment: Do I have to add the autogenerate flag to ALL projects in the solution? Or just the startup one?

Comment: You could find out the conflict projects and add it.

Comment: I have tried all this and it just doesn't seem to work. In 2 of my projects editing the .csproj file and setting the version to 4.2.0.0 breaks code in my project (stateing it can't find the type or namespace name 'Http'

Comment: I did get it to compile, but when it started up I actually got an error on the API itself stating it can't find System.Net.Http 4.0.0.0 which I haven't referenced anywhere and I can't find that in any of my projects

Comment: I did, in all the projects that require it

Comment: You could refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@RupaniChirag/how-to-resolve-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-and-why-this-cf8d48d788eb) to troubleshoot

Comment: I got it to work, I am going to post an answer explaining what I did