# How do I handle long running jobs in Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am rather new to hosting in Azure. I have a .net 4.6 Web app, running in Azure as an App Service.

The solution contains some actions, that run for a long time. These get stopped after a 230 seconds timeout, which seems to be an Azure-thing.

I learned that I should place this code in an Azure Function in order to have it running as a background job. Here there should not be a timeout, as long as I don't use the Consumption plan.

I also use Azure Storage in my solution.

My problem is that if I use Azure Functions v1 (NuGet Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions v1.0.24), I am forced to use Newtonsoft.Json version =9.0.1
Meanwhile NuGet WindowsAzure.Storage requires Newtonsoft.Json version >=10.0.2

That breaks for me.

Then I tried out Azure Functions v2. But it only supports .Net Core, which is not an option for me in this project.

My main issue is still to find a way to be able to run these long running tasks.

One way could be to break the job into smaller parts, but in this case, I would like to be handle it in the same request.

Comment: Take a look at Azure WebJobs. It's the underline resource behind Azure Functions. I believe it supports other platforms beyond .NET Core. [Run Background tasks with WebJobs in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create)

Comment: It does, but it seems, that Web Jobs run in the App Service Context, and also has the 230 seconds limitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you do not have a timeout configured in your hosts.json.

```
"functionTimeout": "00:05:00"
```

The full configuration options for V1 and V2 [are documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout).

In consumption plan, the maximum timeout is 10 minutes. In an app service plan it can be indefinite (but it makes sense to put a cap in, even if it is just 1 or 2 hours).

If you want to break up your functionality, you may find a suitable [Durable Functions pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-concepts).

On your Newtonsoft conflict, see if you can address this [using a binding redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498074/how-can-i-fix-assembly-version-conflicts-with-json-net-after-updating-nuget-pack).

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.9.0.0" newVersion="10.0.2.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was thinking about trying bindingRedirects, but when there is no .config file, where do I put it?

Comment: Add a config file in

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093972/azure-functions-binding-redirect&ved=2ahUKEwi6xLjP9-bfAhVZDWMBHQIKBAgQFjACegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2kdq8jjRMkl2SqLIXwBq3X

Comment: I can't find a good way to combine my backend project, containing a lot of .NET framework tools with the Azure Function 2.0 running .NET Core. It's like issue after issue. So, I guess I have to either find a way to split it into smaller bits, or find a way to run it as a background thread...

Comment: I don't know what your backend project is coded to do, but Azure Functions should stand alone, each one performing a specific function (single responsibility). If your functions depend on backend code, then you will either need to port that code to .net Core as well, or place the code behind a (web) service interface.

Comment: The reason I was considering Azure Functions in the first place was because of an App Service 230-seconds timeout on a long running task. This limitation should not be there on Azure Functions. I understand that it isn't the main purpose with Azure Functions :)

Comment: My `Asp.Net Core Web Api` hosted in S1 app-service-plan times-out after 230 seconds. But I need must longer such as 600 or even 3600 seconds. What can I do ?